# Custom Product Attribute per Category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, product-attribute, custom

I have one problem. Is there a way to set custom attributes to my products when the product is in a category.

Example:
I have two Categories. When I add a product in the first category, I will show the custom attribute brand.
When I add a product in the second category I will show the attribute material.

Has anyone a idea?

Comment: Did you manage to get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to achieve this using attribute sets? I think it's more correct to create two attribute sets - one containing "brand" attribute and another containing "material" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box. However, you could do this by rewriting the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` block class from a custom module editing the `getAdditionalData` method to check for the `current_category` registry key.

The method already has an argument for excluding certain attributes so depending on the category you could exclude or hide either the `brand` or `material` attribute.

Set both attributes to display on product page and this will result the attribute either being shown or hidden depending on the category used to navigate to the product

```
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if ($category->getId() == [category X id]) {
        $excludeAttr[] = '[brand_attribute_code]';
    } elseif ($category->getId() == [category Y id]) {
        $excludeAttr[] = '[material_attribute_code]';
    }

    return parent::getAdditionalData($excludeAttr);
}
```